# Safe way to add new images to Android project

Tags: android, android-drawable, android-resources

I'm working on an application that will require regular addition of images.
At the moment every time I add new images to the drawables folder, indexings get broken (or rebuild) and connections between images and indexes get completely wrong. I'm trying to solve this for a long time now, but with no success. 
Do you guys know a good (safe) way of working with drawables?

Answer (score 1):

If you are using images in your project and need to add more and more images, in the future you'll have problems with the size of the app and performance.

I suggest you to use the [Firebase Storage](https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/?hl=pt-br) the store your files and just reference from App. I'm using in my projects and it works well.